# Merge First Row with the second row of column C if columns A & B are null

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

Need to Merge the second row values with the first row of column C if the rows in columns A&B are null.

DATA:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D
                  14654        
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945        
46456    46485    R68R45
                  AD545    
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

EXPECTED:

```
   A        B       C
12525    1FWE23   1H654D 14654       
                   
24798    14654    S56E82
65116    63546    38945
46456    46485    R68R45 AD545    
                  
A5D66    45346    QA6683
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DSteman I have modified your code to merge the rows only if the next row is null.

Here is the below answer and it works fine for me.

```
df2.loc[df2['A'] != '', 'C'] = df2["C"] + ' ' + df2["C"].shift(-1).fillna("")

df2[df2["A"] != '']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by shifting column C and concating:

```
df["C"] = df["C"] + df["C"].shift(-1).fillna("")
```

Shifting will put `NaN` in column `C` for the last row, hence we fill `NaN` with `""`.

To filter out the rows that have no value in column `A`, we do:

```
df[df["A"] != ""]

>>>

 A       B            C
0  12525  1FWE23  1H654D14654
2  24798   14654  S56E8238945
4  46456   46485  R68R45AD545
6  A5D66   45346       QA6683
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer It works for some scenarios but it does work for the other scenarios where the continuous 2 rows have values.. it should not merge if the next row has value. Updated the question